# How to train two models on two different GPUs with the same data in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

This might be seen as a somewhat simple question, but I'm new to distributed training in Pytorch.

So, I have two defined models (net1 and net2), and two dataloaders for training and testing (train_dl, test_dl), and also I have access to two GPUs ("cuda:0" and "cuda:1"). I have a function called "training" that receives a model, the two dataloaders, and returns the test accuracy. I just need to train both models at the same time; not sequentially, but simultaneously:

```
1 net1.to("cuda:0")
2 net2.to("cuda:1")
3 accuracy1 = training(net1, train_dl, test_dl)
4 accuracy2 = training(net2, train_dl, test_dl)
```

What do I need to do in order to make lines 3 and 4 to execute at the same time? I read something about "spawn" but I have really no clue of how to implement it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the two models are to train independently, you can always just launch a separate python script for each of them? That being said, if you really want to do it in the same script, look into the `multiprocessing` library. Here's a [relevant stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484201/11778344).

Comment: @Gustavo Vargas Hakim

Did you solve your problem ?